# How to configure CICD to develop ssh connection?

Tags: gitlab

[image]I was trying to ssh my gitlab server using CICD as CI is running on runner machine
When i try to ssh gitlab server from runner machine it done successfully but when i try to do the same thing using CICD pipeline it give this output.[image]
 In image 1 i just try to ssh my staging machine only for testing purpose

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
before_script:
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
```

Set the private key variable in Gitlab under Settings > CI / CD > Secret variables.
Name the variable `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` and paste your private key as the value.

Comment: i have got this error ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Comment: And i don't have config file in .ssh. Does this private key is of a runner machine?

Comment: I have three machines A = gitlab server B = staging server C = gitlab runner. Now using CICD i want to ssh server B as CICD runs on runner Server C. When i manually try to ssh from C to B it did perfect but when i use pipeline to do it, it shows error

Comment: So I understand correctly: You are trying to SSH from your gitlab-runner (server C) to your staging server (server B)?

Could you post your .gitlab-ci.yaml?